# Limitations & penalties for using old OpenCV-1.x style C API's, on latest release 2.3.1

Tags: api, opencv, computer-vision

Most of the simpler tutorials, which seem to be easy to begin with, are based on the OpenCV-1.x C-style API's.

I believe that OpenCV-2.3.1 does retain those API's for backward compatibility sake. Wondering if there are performance or other penalties, shortcomings, one might encounter by staying limited to those API's ?

Comment: Absolutely, there are performance improvements in the newer versions. A detailed list can be compiled by reviewing OpenCV's release notes.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply @karlphillip. As a matter of fact, I had found some performance comparisons done by [Shervin Emami](http://www.shervinemami.info/timingTests.html). As you say, performance improvement can be leveraged in case of multi-core processors using libs like TBB on 2.x release, OTOH performance seems to have degraded from OpenCV 1.x to 2.x ! However, that wasn't actually my question :-). What I was trying to find out is, if there is any performance penalty (/gain), by using C-API's over the C++ API's, and are there other limitations due to this choice of API (for 2.3.1)?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that article.

Comment: Well, thank to you, I re-read the article again :-) and it has some of the answers, especially from performance standpoint.